# Can't login with Form Authentication even it was successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

Something really odd is happening to my MVC 4 project.
Everything was fine, I was able to login perfectly... And after a long-time being logged on (about 2 hours), I log out and log on another account, It's not working... There is no error showing up, I have no track for what is wrong... I press "login" button and nothing happens.
But if I do it with that previous version project (the same name) everything is fine.

Any body here ever experiences something like this? I need your help. Thanks in advance! You would save my life.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult login(User user, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (QuanlybangiayEntities3 db = new QuanlybangiayEntities3())
            {
                string username = user.HOVATEN;
                string pass = user.PASSWORD;

                bool UserValid = db.Users.Any(k => k.HOVATEN == username && k.PASSWORD == pass);
                if (UserValid)
                {
                    MigrateShoppingCart(username);

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 &&
                        returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))

                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    else
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Product");
                }
                else
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tên hoặc mật khẩu không đúng!");
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: Note: This code is highly insecure, and seems to be an ecommerce website.. using unecrypted passwords violates payment card industry (PCI) standards and your payment processor could revoke your ability to accept payments.  You should really use secure hashed passwords.

Comment: @Dani. It shows nothing, just stay still